# Unable to locate Secure.java class in Play 1.2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I'm using Eclipse IDE and need to edit Secure.java in Play 1.2.5 according to the forum-https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/G7EsItc_e_s.

The problem now is that I'm unable to locate this class anywhere in my project although I already have the module Secure.

I'm new to Java & Play 1.2.5 itself.

What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

play-1.2.5\play-1.2.5\modules\secure\app\controllers\Secure.java

Comment: But when I use open resource in Eclipse (CTRL+SHIFT+R), Im unable to locate it. Shouldn't it be there in my app when I install it?

Comment: I actually did as you said. Then followed it up with play clean and play deps. My problem is that, i wanted to edit the method "static connect()" to "public static connect()", which I did. But still that method is not accessible. Any help on this part?

Comment: I can't help further myself at the moment I'm afraid.